# add_action with associative array

Tags: filters, actions, parameter

I am trying to get these parameters from the do_action placed inside body:

```
do_action( 'custom_action',  array( 'product_id' => $product_id ,  'outbiddeduser_id' => $outbiddeduser, 'log_id' => $log_id ) );
```

I am trying to do it like this:

```
    add_action('custom_action', 'test', 10, 3);
    function test($product_id, $outbiddeduser_id, $log_id) {
         $a = $product_id;
         $b = $outbiddeduser_id;
         $c = $log_id; 

     echo $a . ', ' . $b . ', ' . $c;
    }
```

And this:

```
add_action('custom_action', 'test', 10, 1);
function test( $associative_array ) {
   $a = $associative_array['product_id'];
   $b = $associative_array['outbiddeduser_id'];
   $c = $associative_array['log_id'];

   echo $a . ', ' . $b . ', ' . $c;
}
```

And it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you testing this? The code examples as is don't have any means of checking if it worked or not

Comment: Updated it again.

Comment: I see, if you don't get what you expected, what do you get instead? And can you update your code so it has values? There are variables, but it's unclear what their values are, which means it might work but it's getting empty values

Answer (score 0):

You passed the action an associative array, so your hooked function will recieve an associative array. It's a little clearer if we retype it like this:

```php
$associative_array = array(
    'product_id' => $product_id ,
    'outbiddeduser_id' => $outbiddeduser,
    'log_id' => $log_id
);
do_action( 'woocommerce_simple_auctions_outbid',  $associative_array );
```

Thus:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_simple_auctions_outbid', 'test', 10, 1);
function test( $associative_array ) {
```

It comes in as an array, because that's what you passed through. There's no magic unpacking of the array in `do_action`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried what you suggested.

Comment: I edited my question now.